# How do I convert this to past tense? "I will keep you update it on every step."

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect, past-continuous

I want to know how could I say or write this sentence in past:

> I will keep you update it on every step

Comment: Your sentence should read: *I will keep you updated on it at every step." Or simply: *I will keep you updated at every step.* The simple past would be: *I kept you updated at every step*, assuming that you did so.

Comment: I kept you updated  during every step (of the process).

Answer (score 1):

The past form of this sentence is simply:

> I kept you updated on/at every step.
>   I kept you updated on it at every step.

*Would* is also the past tense of will in sentences like:

> I said I would keep you updated on/at every step.
>   I said I would keep you updated on it at every step.

Answer (score -1):

The past tense sentence you are looking for is

> I *kept* you updated on/at every step
>   I *have kept* you updated on/at every step.

In present/future tense it is

> I will keep you updat**ed** on/at every step.

meaning you will keep *someone* informed of the progress being made
to put it in the past

Comment: OP asks for the past tense. That's still future!

Comment: Hi Peter, I've edited the question to make it a little more clear that the OP was asking for something in the past tense (even though the sentence they're asking about isn't grammatical). You may want to expand your answer to cover the past tense as well.